# disable caching in apache

Tags: laravel, apache, caching, centos7

thanks in advance.

here is the situation,
there are some images in the system, if a user is authorized to see the images, controller sends image file back to user using this header : 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
otherwise, they'll get a 404 response. as simple as that.

once a user sees one of their images, any unauthenticated user will also be able to send a request and see the image if they are in the same IP range as authenticated user (users in the same city), they won't get 404 anymore,

i have disabled all caching in apache by commenting out all LoadModule lines that are related to caching in conf.modules.d conf files.
i have also checked that apache doesn't use any caching modules `using Httpd -M | grep cache`

the commented out modules are:

- mod_cache.so
- mod_cache_disk.so
- mod_socache_dbm.so
- mod_socache_memcache.so
- mod_socache_shmcb.so

i have also written the following block in my htaccess, RewriteEngine is on, and AllowOverride is set to All.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

there are no other caching mechanisms available in the OS,

Backend is Laravel 7,
OS is Centos 7,
Apache is Apache/2.4.6,

Comment: I don't see any point here. What is the problem exactly? Seems like everything is working fine...

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana  thanks for your reply.
the problem is, once any authenticated user views any of their images, the image will be publicly accessible by anyone, without being authorized or authenticated,
the requests for that particular image don't get to the controller anymore, as if a caching system is still responding and not the controller.

Comment: Maybe laravel is caching stuff.

Comment: I found this. https://krishan.blog/articles/2019-11-02/disable-cache-in-laravel#:~:text=To%20disable%20the%20cache%20you,value%20to%20none%20in%20your%20. Do it at your own risk. I have never used laravel. I am not sure what it does. Maybe you can figure it out. Or wait for someone to answer your question :)